# Pygame Window created in the background

Tags: python, pygame

When I start my program that has to open pygame window, it opens it behind the current window. What have I to write to make a focus on pygame window and it won't be as background?  This is for a game for mathematics revision so I need to use the python shell as well, in this example for (1+1).
This is the code I run. (just as an example)

```
import pygame
play = input("DO you want to play the game(y,n): ")
if play == "y":
    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 24, bold = False, italic = False )
    Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    black = (0,0,0)
    Screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")
    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, (218,123,255), ((0,0),(600,20)),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, (0,197,243), ((0,20),(800, 580)), 16)
    pygame.display.update()
    #Play game for some time
    Add = input("1 + 1 = ")
    #Continue game on the pygame window
```

Comment: it looks wierd when game with graphic uses console and input() to ask for answers. You could display question in PyGame and use pygame's events to get pressed key(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to have the system position the pygame window in front of all the other ones is to not use the Python Shell.

Aside from doing that I do not think that there is any way to change how the system positions the window in pygame. I haven't found anything that changes whether it is positioned behind or in front of the current window. Correct me if I am wrong but I would guess that is the OS's job.

Thus, you must do everything in Pygame or else you will have the user switching between windows.

**To fix this problem**:

- Remove all uses of the `input` function and use of the Python shell.
- Implement a way to ask the mathematics questions in Pygame using *font rendering*
- Implement a way to let the user type in an answer and enter it in. This can be done using *font rendering* and *input handling*.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!